# Ellipses on BIGQUERY Result Panel

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, coursera-api

I need to expand column and get rid of the ellipses (....) on the results panel of BIGQUERY SQL to show complete values

[image: Average_values column]

I have tried to hover the cursor on the results like in excel but it would not change the cursor so I can drag or adjust

Comment: In my console there is a "grab bar" in the bottom right of the column header where I can resize the column width.  I notice in your screen shot that it isn't present.  Can you post which browser and platform you are viewing the console upon?  I'm using Chrome on a Chrome book.

Comment: I was using Mozilla, I just switched to Chrome and I can now see the Grab Bar you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).